# Using floating action button to send email to developer

Tags: java, android, material-design

I would like to be able to give users the ability to email the developer by pressing on the email fab icon. It should open up like a share intent.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For FAB tutorial, please checkout from AndroidHive's Tutorial
http://www.androidhive.info/2015/12/android-material-design-floating-action-button/

To send email to developer.

```
FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               Intent Email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            Email.setType("text/email");
            Email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL,
                    new String[]{"developeremail@gmail.com"});  //developer 's email
            Email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,
                    "Add your Subject"); // Email 's Subject
            Email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Dear Developer Name," + "");  //Email 's Greeting text
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(Email, "Send Feedback:"));
            }
        });
```

Comment: This will work, thanks